# Jsviews filter search

Tags: search, filter, jsviews

How do I create a filter search in JSViews? Usually I'd grab the html element by its class with the .getElementsByClassName() and .value() methods and add a === comparison to satisfy the right criteria. How can I do something similar in JsViews

I've already tried to add listItem in the IF to match the value of the html input (search bar), but I don't know how to grab the value of the search element (JQuery would be easy using $(".search")), or compare it to the listItems using regExp.

```
{^{if list && list.length}}
<ul autoselectitem="true" tabindex="-1" operationalindex="1" allindex="1">
    {^{for list}}
          {{include tmpl="listItem" /}}
    {{/for}}
</ul> 
 {{else}}

     <p>Nothing Found</p>

{{/if}}
```

This currently displays all items in the list, however I only want the elements in the list to be displayed that match with RegEx the .value of an search HTML element:

```
<input type="text" class="search" data-link="search" placeholder="Search...">
```

So for example, if I type in "e" into the search bar, all the items in the list that don't have the letter "e" should disappear.

The code linked all work, but what i've tried has given me null pointer errors because I'm not grabing the input element correctly by its class or data-link. How could I do this in the simplest way possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <input type="text" class="search" data-link="search" placeholder="Search...">

  {^{if list && list.length}}
    <ul autoselectitem="true" tabindex="-1" operationalindex="1" allindex="1">
      {^{for list filter=~flt depends="search"}}
        <li data-link="#data"></li>
      {{/for}}
    </ul> 
  {{/if}}
</script>

<div id="page"></div>

<script>
  var myTmpl = $.templates("#myTmpl"),
    data = {
      list: ["a", "b"],
      search: ""
    },
    helpers = {
    flt: function(item, index, items) {
      return item.indexOf(data.search) > -1;
    }};
  myTmpl.link("#page", data, helpers);
</script>
```